# returning observable from Angular5 http.get

Tags: angular

I have an Interface

```
export interface IEmployee{
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
}
```

In my employee.service.ts

```
  getEmployess():Observable<IEmployee>{
    return this._http.get<IEmployee>(this._dataUrl);
  }
```

In my component

```
  employees:Array<IEmployee>;   

  constructor(private _employeeService:EmployeeService){
    this._employeeService.getEmployess()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.employees = data;
          console.log(data);
        }
      )
  }
```

I am gettign the erro **[ts] Type 'IEmployee' is not assignable to type 'IEmployee[][]'.**

I am unable to understand whats wrong. I want that the returned data from service should be stored in employees array.

Please help.

Comment: Your service return type is Observable<IEmployee>. So, each event emitted by this observable is **one** IEmployee. You're trying to store **that** IEmployee into a variable of type Array<IEmployee>. That can't work. An egg box is not the same thing as an egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason of issue:**

```
this.employees = data;  
// this.employees is type of IEmployee[]
// data is type of IEmployee
```

---

**Solution** -> Just change :

```
getEmployess():Observable<IEmployee>
```

To

```
getEmployess():Observable<IEmployee[]>{
// OR
getEmployess():Observable<Array<IEmployee>>{
```

> As you are getting array of `IEmployee` in return and you have defined
>   `employees:Array<IEmployee>;`

Answer (score 2):

return

```
 getEmployess():Observable< Array<IEmployee>>{
    return this._http.get<Array<IEmployee>>(this._dataUrl);
  }
```

or

```
getEmployess():Observable< IEmployee[]>{
    return this._http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._dataUrl);
  }
```

Comment: its better to unsubscribe by assigning to one variable